# Wordpress custom widget with social icons

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am trying to create a custom widget where the user can select the types of social media he wants to display and then enter his social url's.

So I need to be able to select multiple images to appear when selected and I also need to be able to set a url for those images to direct to.

I've just spent 3 hours searching for something to help me but since I'm not so PHP savvy as I wish I was I haven't come any further than this;

```
class SocialWidget extends WP_Widget
{
  function SocialWidget()
  {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'SocialWidget', 'description' => 'Display Social Icons' );
    $this->WP_Widget('SocialWidget', 'Social Icons', $widget_ops);
  }

  function form($instance)
  {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '' ) );
    $title = $instance['title'];
?>
  <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($title); ?>" /></label></p>
<?php
  }

  function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
  {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    return $instance;
  }

  function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    echo $before_widget;
    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

    if (!empty($title))
      echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;;

    // WIDGET CODE GOES HERE
    echo "<h1>This is my new widget!</h1>";

    echo $after_widget;
  }

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("SocialWidget");') );?>
```

And I learned this by following a tutorial. It sets the widget title and so far it only displays a simple message so I could see it works.

Now, can anyone help me get on the right foot here? When I describe what I need it sounds so easy but still I cannot find how to do this anywhere. Is it not so simple and should I leave it be or is it doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I start note that all code was only typed into the browser and not checked.  Also, I write widgets all the time so I understand how and why these things can be confusing.  So I'm going to try and give you a very short answer so you might just be able to copy and paste code right in.  If you need a longer answer then please check the Wordpress docs [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).

There are a couple main things you need to do.  Add a new settings field for each social media site you want the user to be able to display (you could just add one as an array but that might be to hard for your level).  Then you need settings field to store the url associated with each social media channel.  They you can set it up by have checkboxes for each social media channel for the user to display and a associating text field for the url to link to.

So like your title add all your url link fields you want

```
<p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('url_1'); ?>">Url 1: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('url_1'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('url_1'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_url($url_1); ?>" /></label></p>
```

then add the line so they will be saved

```
$instance['url_1'] = $new_instance['url_1'];
```

and then in your widget function add this to display the link

```
echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . $instance['url_1'] . '">URL 1</a>';
```

thats just for getting a link to show up.  There are more steps to take for the checkboxes and the images, but if this is way too hard for you then you might have to leave it be.  Overall for a PHP developer this an easy task and you can probably call upon a developer to get it done.

Hope it all works out,

Kyle

Comment: Sadly this is out of my league still so I will just ask a developer to help me with this. I like to understand the basics of the code so I'll also look into PHP a bit more. Thanks a lot for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I have created similar plugin and is available in WordPress Plugin directory. Click link below to see my plugin:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wens-social-links/

You can download it and analyze it. I hope it will be great help to support your requirement. 
Thanks.